# Unable to access shared folders on a domain using a workgroup PC (W7 home premium)

Tags: windows-7, networking, network-shares

I do know that a Windows 7 Home premium does not have the "**join to a domain**" feature. But shouldn't they be able to access a shared drive on a domain?, as I've seen some can access.

However, I've been having difficulties to fix such a workstation which can ping the destination server but does not offer username/password prompt to access the said server shares. I've tried the registry editing method to overcome this issue; which didn't work too.

Any help or advise on this will be great.

Comment: How can this be a duplicate as I'm not trying to connect the PCs to domain but to access the folders. Further, I've mentioned that know it...?

Comment: One of the answers in the duplicate addresses folder access...